# How to render elements based on dynamic keys in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, ecmascript-6

My API shows:

```
{
    "IB": [
        {
            "id": 2,
            "title": "Authorization",
            "description": null,
            "developer": 4,
            "submitter": 1,
            "priority": "M",
            "status": "IB"
        }
    ],
    "EM": [],
    "IP": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Fix Header and Footer",
            "description": "Use better css for the header",
            "developer": 5,
            "submitter": 1,
            "priority": "M",
            "status": "IP"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "title": "Fix routing",
            "description": "Created nested routing with react router",
            "developer": 5,
            "submitter": 1,
            "priority": "M",
            "status": "IP"
        }
    ],
    "TS": [],
    "CO": []
}
```

I can display the values in React with the following repetitive code:

```
      <div className='col' id='IB'>
        {loading ? null :
          data['IB'].map((item, index) => <div key={index}><div className='ticket'>{item.title}</div></div>)
        }
      </div>
      <div className='col' id='EM'>
        {loading ? null :
          data['EM'].map((item, index) => <div key={index}><div className='ticket'>{item.title}</div></div>)
        }
      </div>
      <div className='col' id='IP'>
        {loading ? null :
          data['IP'].map((item, index) => <div key={index}><div className='ticket'>{item.title}</div></div>)
        }
      </div>
      <div className='col' id='TS'>
        {loading ? null :
          data['TS'].map((item, index) => <div key={index}><div className='ticket'>{item.title}</div></div>)
        }
      </div>
      <div className='col' id='CO'>
        {loading ? null :
          data['CO'].map((item, index) => <div key={index}><div className='ticket'>{item.title}</div></div>)
        }
      </div>
```

But when I tried to loop it like this, nothing shows up in the app.

```
      {loading ? null : statuses.forEach(status => {
        <div className='col' id={status}>
          {
            data[status].map((item, index) => <div key={index}><div className='ticket'>{item.title}</div></div>)
          }
        </div>
      })}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` method of the array doesn't return anything. You should use `Object.entries` and `map` instead of it. I cannnot check it but idea is:

```
    {loading ? null : Object.entiries(statuses).map(([key, value) => {
        return <div className='col' id={key}>
          {
            value.map((item, index) => <div key={index}><div className='ticket'>{item.title}</div></div>)
          }
        </div>
      })}
```